# Difference between a point mass and a rotating disk

Tags: rotational-dynamics

In Kinematics, we deal with particles (point masses) which do not have any rotation about their mass centres. In books, it is often mentioned that bodies are analysed as particles but only motion of an entire number of particles making a unit is considered. How does this statement valid for mechanical vibrations where we considered SDOF and MDOF systems? As an example, if we take the case of a rotating disk on a shaft, the equation of motion is $J\ddot{\theta}+K \theta=0$, then is it as I written above a system in which an entire number of particles is forming a unit (the disk)?

Here is an extract from the book "Vector mechanics for engineers: Dynamics, ninth edition by Beer"":

[image]

Comment: @Rob Thank you. I've put the link. I've asked the question here so as to have a physicist point of view.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking.

Comment: I have received a good answer that has  shed light on my misunderstanding. Not sure why this 1 vote down if someone is not willing to take time to understand a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**When can I use the classical particle description?**

Think of the particle description as the most basic model you can make. We neglect any features of the body and track the motion of its center of mass, giving us $3$ degrees of translational freedom.

**When does the particle description fail?**

Generally speaking, if the features of the body are important to its dynamics, then the particle description is going to be lacking.

Consider a fixed coordinate system in space, whose origin is initially at the center of mass of the object. Now set up another set of axes that point along three fixed directions along the body and whose origin is defined to be at the center of mass. If the relative angles between these two sets of axes - that of the spatial and bodily axes- ever change, then the body is rotating in space. We then cannot describe it as a particle having $3$ degrees of freedom.

By neglecting any deformation of the macroscopic shape, the constituent particles of the body preserve their position in the body-centered frame. We call this [rigid body dynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigid_body_dynamics). This model characterizes the motion of the macroscopic body through the translation and rotation of its body axes with respect to the spatially fixed frame, meaning we need up to $6$ degrees of freedom.

**What about the rotating disc?**

For a rotating disc, we require rigid body dynamics. Even if a flywheel's axis is off-center, its bodily coordinates are still rotating with respect to some spatial coordinates (see comment). By constraining the translational motion and confining the rotation along a single axis, we end up considering dynamics with respect to one angle, say $\theta$.

**Further reading**

For further information, I recommend David Tong's [lecture notes on The Dynamics of Rigid Bodies](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/dynamics.html), freely accessible on his website.

Comment: I've added an extract from a book in the post. The extract from the book seems to point out that to analyse a body like a disk as a single entire unit, the disk is treated as a particle. This particle does not have any rotation about its own mass centre. But if this rotation is not negligible, then according to the textbook extract, we have to resort to the topic of dynamics of rigid bodies. For a disk on a shaft, the mass centre may not be at the point where the shaft go through the disk. So based on my understanding, this is contradictory to the answer that you gave.

Comment: The author of the excerpt is stating that the particle description is insufficient when there is rotation about the center of mass. That's correct. Don't confuse this with the location of the axis of rotation. Even if the axis is off-center, the bodily axes may still rotate with respect to the spatial frame.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking away my misunderstanding. Answer is definitely clearer now.